# Groovy REST endpoint testing alternative

Tags: testing, groovy, spock, endpoint, endpoints

I've been having problems using Groovy HttpBuilder/RESTClient to do endpoint testing in Groovy:

1. It always gives me a long error message about log4j appenders, which clutters the output even in success.
2. Failure is not expressed in terms of assertion failure, but in HttpResponderExceptions.

I'm guessing these are both inherited from the Apache base used for HttpBuilder. Is there a decent (hopefully standard) client out there in Java or Groovy to do basic REST endpoint testing?

Thank you

Comment: Provide an example illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's [groovy-rest](https://github.com/gschueler/groovy-rest), though the project doesn't seem very active.

And then there's also [groovy-wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite) which seems more maintained and also includes SOAP support.

If you try them out, let us know how it goes, RESTClient has often annoyed me a lot :)